# How to check if existing user_login in WordPress and create new user programatically by appending to an existing user_login

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WP v5.8.1, I am creating new user programmatically from public forms, using `wp_create_user`. New user_login will be created by combining `first_name` and `last_name`

```
$new_username = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['first_name']) . '-' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['last_name']));
```

However, chances are there might be an existing user with same user_login. Hence I want to append number (1,2,3,4,etc) to the new `user_login` with below function:

```
if (username_exists($new_username)) {
    create_new_username();
} else {
    $new_username = $new_username;
}

function create_new_username() {
    $count = 0;
    while (username_exists($new_username)) :
        $new_username = $new_username . '-' . $count + 1;
        $count++;

        if (!username_exists($new_username)) {
            $create_username = $new_username;
        }
    endwhile;

    return $new_username;
}

echo create_username();
```

If `user_login` exists, the above function returns existing `user_login` user ID; it is not creating new `user_login` with appending with number.

**Edit 1:**

I have modified the code as below without writing a separate function:

```
$new_username = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['first_name']) . '-' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['last_name']));

if (username_exists($new_username)) {
    $count = 0;
    while (username_exists($new_username)) :
        $new_username = $new_username . '-' . ($count + 1);
        $count++;

    endwhile;
}
echo $new_username;
```

This is returning a new `user_login` if user exists; however instead of appending a new series number from `($count + 1)`, it is adding another new number as below:

- first-last
- first-last-1
- first-last-1-2
- first-last-1-2-3

Whereas I need the usernames like this:

- first-last
- first-last-1
- first-last-2
- first-last-3

Comment: Why not just use email?

Comment: `user_login` will be used in user profile URL like `https://www.example.com/user/firstname-lastname-1`.

Comment: You need to pass `$new_userrname` as a variable to your function.

Comment: `$new_username` is the variable defined before the function. it holds the values of first and last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, comments from @Howard E has helped me to achieve what I am looking for:

Below is the new user name created from the public form submission:

```
$new_username = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['first_name']) . '-' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['last_name']));
```

With below code, I am able to check if the `user_login` is exists, if exists appending a serial number to create new `user_login`:

```
    if (username_exists($new_username)) { // check if user_login exists
    while (username_exists($new_username)) :
        $count = preg_match_all("/.*?(\d+)$/", $new_username, $matches); // check if the existing user_login has serialised number at the end
        if ($count) { // if user_login has number at the end
            $new_username = rtrim($new_username, '-' . $count); // remove the number and '-' also before the number 
        } else {
            $count = 0; // else keep the count as 0 to add to the submitted user_login from the public form
        }
        $new_username = $new_username . '-' . ($count + 1); // this will create a new serialised user_login with numbering continuation from previous, else create new user_login as per form submission
        $count++;

    endwhile;
}
echo $new_username;
```

Now this is creating user_logins as below:

- first-last
- first-last-1
- first-last-2
- first-last-3

Please comment if the code can be still be more simpler and efficient?

Comment: I still don't see why you need a while loop?  How could there be more than one username?  If the username is `first-last-3` you want the next one to be `first-last-4` regardless if there is a 1 - 3 in there.  But at any rate, `$new_username` should never be more than 1 item.

Comment: The while loop is necessary. It handles the case where `first-last-1` and `first-last-2` both exist (and so on). The loop is the only way you can get to the last number that already exists.

Comment: Also, since this is untrusted user input from the `$_POST` variable it needs to be sanitized before use. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/ would be a good function to use for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `create_new_username()` needs the variable `$new_username` it's not automatically passed to this function, and therefore is undefined.

```
function create_new_username($new_username) {
    $count = 0;
    while (username_exists($new_username)) :
        $new_username = $new_username . '-' . $count + 1;
        $count++;

        if (!username_exists($new_username)) {
            $create_username = $new_username;
        }
    endwhile;

    return $new_username;
}
```

Then however you're getting to your `if(username_exists())` call... I'd have to assume through some other hook, you would have to pass the variable `$new_username` to your `username_exists()` function.

```
if (username_exists($new_username)) {
    create_new_username($new_username);
}
```

Since your `else` doesn't do anything, it's not necessary.  `$new_username` already is equal to `$new_username`

Comment: Even after passing the `$new_username` variable into the function, `user_id` of the existing user was returning. So I have modified the code without a separate function which is returning a new `user_login` but it is appending numbers in series.

Comment: Your update makes it a different question.  Why would there be a condition that returns multiple results for `while (username_exists($new_username)` ? You need to evaluate the value of an appended number at the end of your new-username-`number` if there's a number add 1.

Comment: Yes, see my answer.